# How to add a .css to a .cshtml

Tags: html, css, razor

I'm a complete HTML/CSS novice and I am trying to get a .cshtml file to use some basic CSS I wrote.  What code do I need to put in my .cshtml to get it to use the CSS file?

Edit: This is the code in my .css file. It is intended to style my `div` with the id of "comment_box1", but even after following the answer, it's not working. Any idea what's wrong?

```
.comment_box1 {
    background-color: #C8E0E8; 
    width: 830px; 
    height: 180px; 
}
```

Comment: A complete example would have been helpful as the problem obviously was not in the code shown, but in the code *not* shown.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here is the basic option - you add a style tag to the `<head>` of your document...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
```

If you are using bundles, you place the bundle there instead:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

And finally, if you are using a master layout, that's the best place to put this as it will then apply to all your pages.

**Update**

If you are targeting an id, you use `#`, rather than the dot, which is for a class.

```
#comment_box1
{
background-color: #C8E0E8; 
width: 830px; 
height: 180px; 
}
```

Comment: @user1394965 it might possible other user not expecting answer on this type question by a high rep men ...

Comment: Added a quick edit of a problem I'm still having, sorry if I'm being a complete novice.

Comment: @Smoore I have added an extra bit for that.

Comment: Just to mention: `@Styles.Render` can not only be used with bundles but also with "ordinary" css files. This is useful if for generating relative URL (`~` gets replaced by the base URL)

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/yourApp.styles.css" type="text/css" />`

Answer (score 12):

You could also make the use of  while using CSS in .cshtml files. In this case, paste the following code directly into your .cshtml file:

```
<style>
#comment_box1
{
background-color: #C8E0E8; 
width: 830px; 
height: 180px; 
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

**dotnet core**

First, make sure you have `wwwroot` folder and put your `css` file inside it.

Second, check if you have `app.UseStaticFiles();` in you `startup.cs` `Configure` method

Third, link to your files using a path like this `~/style.css` based on the path from `wwwroot`

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0)