# How to add css file to cshtml file?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-core

I've been trying to add a css file to style a cshtml file, and so far I've been unsuccessful.

Here's what I've tried to do:

```
    @model mvc.Models.LoginViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
}

<head>
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="display-4">Login Page</h1>
    </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/login.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

[Here is the directory tree with the two files I'm trying to link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UaKW.png)

Edit:  when I put the css styling in a "style" tag in the cshtml then it works. I was hoping there was a way to do it with a css file.

Can you please help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a .css to a .cshtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144234/how-to-add-a-css-to-a-cshtml)

Comment: I've tried that, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: and `href="/Content/login.css"`

Comment: ../../Content/login.css you need to up 2 folder. Now your link Views/content/login.css you need to go /Content/login.css

Comment: I tried going up two folders, still didn't work.

Comment: Did you refresh page after go up two folders

Comment: @VDWWD I tried href="/Content/login.css" and it didn't work

Comment: @erdiyılmaz Yes, I refreshed the page and I even restarted the Terminal and it still didn't work.

Comment: Please press F2 key and look from source where is your css and cshtml file

Comment: @erdiyılmaz I posted a pic with the directory tree. The files didn't move... Why should I check where they are from the source?

Comment: Maybe your browser or your IIS setup cause this.

Comment: @erdiyılmaz when I put the css styling in a "style" tag in the cshtml then it works. I was hoping there was a way to do it with a css file.

Comment: Your href doesnt match with your souerce address in your project if you look from browser source you can find your css file adress

Answer (score 1):

From your project structure, I think you may misunderstand asp.net and asp.net core. .NET 5 is the next version of .NET Core.

You use .NET 5.0, so if you want to directly add css reference, you need add these static files to **wwwroot folder in root project**. Be sure you have added static files middleware in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();   //be sure add this...
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
});
```

Then add reference like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/login.css" />
```

Reference:  [Serve files in web root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0#serve-files-in-web-root)

If you put static files to **other folder(e.g Content folder) which is in root project**, you need add the following code to Startup.cs first:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //...
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();   // For the wwwroot folder.

    // using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
    // using System.IO;
    app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "Content")),
        RequestPath = "/StaticFiles",
        EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true
    });

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Add static files reference like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/StaticFiles/login.css" />
```

Reference:  [Serve files outside of web root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root)